# Inputs to VSTS custom powershell task

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm trying to createa powershell task to wrap up some functionality, the problem I have it, my variables aren't resolving properly prior.

A redacted task.json is below, specifying an that won't resolve. I want my appUrl var to resolve `$(systemEnvironment)` also, before it's passed to powershell.

at a VSTS level, it looks to resolve properly, but when it gets to powershell it's wrong.

Initialisation task:
`[APPURL] --> [dev1-my-app.company]`

Powershell Exec:
`2019-05-24T10:33:56.5386650Z ##[debug]PowerShellHandler.Execute - AddParameter(appUrl=$(systemEnvironment)-my-app.company)`

Task.json

```
{
    "name": "Runner",
    "instanceNameFormat": "Run tests against $(systemEnvironment)",
    "inputs": [
        {
            "name": "appUrl",
            "type": "string",
            "label": "The application  URL",
            "defaultValue": "$(systemEnvironment)-my-app.company",
            "required": true,
            "helpMarkDown": "The application URL `($appUrl)`"
        },
        {
            "name": "systemEnvironment",
            "type": "string",
            "label": "The environment",
            "defaultValue": "DEV1",
            "required": true,
            "helpMarkDown": "The environment the tests run against"
        }
}
```

task.ps1

```
[CmdletBinding()] 
param(
    [string][Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $appUrl)

my-power-shell-code
```

Have a missed a trick here?

Comment: Your task.json is missing the execution-properties where you define which script runs when (pre-job,job,post-job) and your ps1-script doesn't use param(...) for inputs but a method 'get-vstsinput' from the module 'vststasksdk'. Here is the vsbuild-task for example: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/VSBuildV1/VSBuild.ps1 .You still need to download the module and copy it next to your ps1 but i forgot how the subfolder should be named, gotta dig up some code later

Comment: You can't reference any other inputs in another input as far as i know. you'll have to assemble theese two in your ps1-code

Comment: `Get-TaskVariable` is just a shortcut to `Env:$variable`

Comment: I'll make changes like you've suggested.

Comment: i know that 'Get-TaskVariable' is just a shortcut to 'env:$variable', i didn't mention this method but 'Get-VstsInput'

Comment: Oh you're right, I've looked at completely the wrong thing.